# How to disable auto-update for virtual machines in Azure?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, automatic-updates

In my azure environment there are sets of virtual machines that are rebooting at the same time, I assume it has to do with auto-update settings. How do I turn off the auto-updates and enable manual scheduling for Azure Virtual Machine updates? When I go to the update blade it doesn't provide me any options.

Answer (score -1):

You can configure [Update Management for an Azure VM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/update-management/enable-from-vm)

> This article describes how you can enable the Update Management feature on one or more Azure virtual machines (VM). To enable Azure VMs at scale, you must enable an existing Azure VM using Update Management.

[image]

But IMO a better approach is to use a [scale set with automatic updates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-automatic-upgrade)

> Enabling automatic OS image upgrades on your scale set helps ease update management by safely and automatically upgrading the OS disk for all instances in the scale set.

> **Within a 'set':**
> All VMs in a common scale set are not updated concurrently.
> VMs in a common virtual machine scale set are grouped in batches and updated within Update Domain boundaries as described below.